# How can I import multiple portlets in Liferay?

Tags: jsf, liferay-7

I am having trouble importing more than one portlet in Liferay 7.4.3-85. When usnig cdi all portlets render same view. When inspecting element portlets have different id, name, etc. I use thick cdi packaging from maven archetype com.liferay.faces.archetype.parent

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>lala</portlet-name>
        <display-name>lala</display-name>
        <portlet-class>javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
            <value>/views/lala.xhtml</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>lala</title>
            <short-title>lala</short-title>
            <keywords>lala</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>boom</portlet-name>
        <display-name>boom</display-name>
        <portlet-class>javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
            <value>/views/boom.xhtml</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>boom</title>
            <short-title>boom</short-title>
            <keywords>boom</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

both specified portlets render /views/lala.xhtml.

Whole project is available on Github: https://github.com/KristjanBulic/liferay-example